# Can I decrypt a dm-crypt filesystem on OS X?

Tags: security, encryption, unix

I've been an Ubuntu user for years, and I just got my first Mac. One thing I haven't yet figured out is how to decrypt my encrypted filesystem on which I store my SSH and GPG keys on my flash drive. I used [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GPGKeyOnUSBDrive) in the past to set it up, and have just been running the shell script to decrypt and mount it since then.

However, I cannot figure out how to decrypt it on OS X. Running `brew install cryptsetup` doesn't work.

Comment: `cryptsetup` isn't a brew package

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/110032/how-to-mount-an-encrypted-ext3-filesystem-under-os-x and particularly this answer: http://superuser.com/a/130910/63543

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/604554/encrypted-filesystem-shared-with-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2):

You may try [OSXCrypt](http://www.osxcrypt.org/) which is a kernel extension and a command line utility that allows the creation, manipulation and attaching of a TrueCrypt-compatible volumes.

See also ext4fuse or fuse4x (via brew).

Or try to install a tiny linux distro (e.g. [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)) in a virtual machine (e.g. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) and then install/configure cryptsetup.

I don't know if hdiutil can handle it, but here is an example:

```
sudo hdiutil attach -stdinpass -encryption AES-256 /dev/disk1s1
```

To check how your hardrive is encrypted, try the following command:

```
sudo cat /dev/disk1s1 | strings -3 | head
```

See also:

- [Password Cracking AES-256 DMGs and Epic Self-Pwnage](http://blog.whitehatsec.com/cracking-aes-256-dmgs-and-epic-self-pwnage/)